# MS Access - Editing a query's sql with vba - change "SELECT Top n"

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Context - I'm building an access database that keeps track of sailboat races and calculates overall season scores as well as smaller "series" of scores. However, in a "series" not every race is counted. For example, if a series has 10 races, I only want to count the top 7 races of each individual person.

I have a separate query that is able to calculate the number of races actually counted based on the total number in each series. The query I am working on now calculates each individual's score by adding up their points for their top "n" races in that series. I don't have an extensive knowledge in sql or vba, but I was able to figure out how to use the "SELECT Top n" to filter each individual's top scores and then use a SUM to get the total.

The problem I have now is that the "n" has to be adaptable because the series could have any number of races. After some research, I learned that the only way to alter "SELECT TOP" is to use vba to rewrite the query's definition. I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish this- I don't even know where to put the code to alter the query in vba.

Again, I don't have much experience in vba, but I'm eager to learn in order to accomplish what I need. Any help is appreciated and I can show my sql if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you want to store the value of the number of races in a series into a variable, and use that variable in your `Top N` query.

```
Dim Db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim series As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("YourTableNameOrQueryName")
'Here we can open the Table and store the number of series into a variable.

series = rs!YourSeriesCountFieldInTableOrQuery

Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT Top " & series & " races FROM YourTable"
' You can ensure you have the right number of series by setting a break point or
' Using Debug.Print (SQL) to see the SQL in the output window.

db.Execute "SQL", dbFailOnError

'The SQL string would be your query that you have working, as posted in your OP.
'The only difference would be the string concatenation of the number of series that is dynamic


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure I understand all of this, it makes sense. My next question though is in MS access itself, where in visual basic will I add this code so that I can use it when I run my query?

Comment: No problem. So in Access, at the top, the tab `Database Tools`. Click on it. To the very left is `Visual Basic`. Click on that. This is where the code-behind for all form operations/modules/reports resides. You can put a button on a form that triggers this code, you can create a module, and use the `Call Module` code to run this code.

Comment: @sail10694 To run this code with a button click, add a button to your form in design view. (Right click on your form in the Access Object List, `Design View`.) Add a button. Press Cancel. Right click on the button. Properties. Event Tab. On Click (click the 3 little dots [`...`]). Code Builder.

Comment: Is it possible to have a query already defined and then execute this code to alter it whenever query is run?

Comment: You can literally go to the query in design view, top left, click the View drop down arrow to the very left. Click SQL. Copy and paste your SQL into the variable `SQL` in the code I wrote, and edit the `Top N` segment as I have it.

Comment: I understand that part fully. I have no problem editing your code so that it works with my sql. I'm just wondering if there is a way to build a form or report based off of this query that is able to change for each series

Comment: Well, you would have to think. Is there a textbox that you can narrow the series down with? You have to kind of think of terms of a) what data do you want to show and b) how are you going to get the data. So we know only know part of a, and we know part of b. We need to find the missing piece, and that would be up to you. Do you want to design a field that narrows down the series that users are typing into a text box? A checkbox? There are a couple ways it could go, however, I'm not sure of your table schema so I can't accurately answer the question.

Comment: Ok I did some more research and found what I needed. I used the QueryDefs method to rewrite the sql of my existing query using your help and then I used that code in the Form_Load() of the form I wanted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm really happy you got it. I hope you understand it! That's a very important piece, also. Good luck with the rest of your app/project.